# Is it possible in Azure Release pipeline to clone a Git repo from another team project?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

So I have set up a release pipeline and want to link both a build pipeline as well as a Git repo as artifacts. That all works well, I've tried it in another pipeline already. But when I try to clone a repo that is located in another team project as the pipeline I get a Git error 128:

```
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier my_repo.git does not exist or you do not have permission for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://MyUrl/MyCollection/MyProject/_git/my_repo.git/' not found
#[error]Downloading artifacts failed: System.InvalidOperationException: Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
```

However it is possible to select repos from other team projects, so I think it should work in theory. Is this possible at all, or do I have to change some security settings so that it works? If so, how would I do that?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: This might help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-repositories-resource

Comment: I am not sure if this method will solve the issue, but on Project Settings -> Pipelines -> Settings -> You can deselect Limit job authorization scope to referenced Azure Devops Repositories.

Comment: Thanks so much @GeralexGR, that was my problem. I don't know why it was selected on one of my team projects, while being deselected on others, but that just saved my day!

Comment: @DanDan let me add it as an answer to make the question completed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should go to Project Settings -> Pipelines -> Settings and deselect **Limit job authorization scope to referenced Azure Devops Repositories**.

This is by default checked on Azure DevOps projects.